# Get substring image name

Tags: java, android

I have a string like `myweb.com/blabla/blabla/image.jpg` How could I get substring that starts at the end and ends when first "/" char? Expected string will be `image.jpg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String string = "myweb.com/blabla/blabla/image.jpg";    
string.subString(string.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Below Code for that.

```
String s="myweb.com/blabla/blabla/image.jpg";
int i=s.lastIndexOf("/");
s=s.substring(i+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Being `String.substring` clearly the solution for generic case, there is another way of doing your particular task in android:

```
String url = "myweb.com/blabla/blabla/image.jpg";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
uri.getLastPathSegment();
```

getLastPathSegment in you case will return image.jpg. Apart from that you can easilly extract other information using uri object.

Comment: but if he never needs a Uri, is it better to create one just to call its last segment over the substring way?

Answer (score 1):

```
String name = fullpath.subString(fullpath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

fullPath being the `myweb.com/blabla/blabla/image.jpg`

Comment: I want "image" only not extension("image.jpg") ..can you help me

Answer (score 1):

Use `lastIndexOf` method of String class..

```
String string = "myweb.com/blabla/blabla/image.jpg ";
String imageName = string.subString(string.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the File class.  Has everything you need to get paths, filenames, extensions etc.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

getName() will help.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29)